# No module found error after executing exe generated using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I am having my project structure like this

```
ab_folder
    ---ab.py
    ---abc.py
ab_report
    ---ab_report.py
    ---utils.py
```

My main file is `ab.py` in ab_folder which uses `abc.py` file plus it also imports file `ab_report.py`  file from **ab_report** folder. I am using the following code in `ab.py` to switch and import method of **ab_report** folder

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../ab_report")
from ab_report import PDFRepoort
```

Now currently I am generated exe's of my `ab.py` file(which is my main file) using pyinstaller.
While reading **pyinstaller** docs I understand that we have to give directory via `--paths` arguments if our code changes `sys.path`.

SO My current directory is `ab_folder` and in this directory i opened my console and did run the following line to generate `ab.spec` file

```
pyi-makespec --paths=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Deploy_Exe_Test\ab_report ab.py
```

After this i do run `pyinstaller ab.py` command to generate exe in dist folder but when I run that exe I get error that

**`No module named ab_report`**

I think my issues maybe lies in giving path parameter. Looking for valuable suggestions and help. Also how much this generated exe will be securable(Hard to reverse)?

My python version is **3.6.6**